# Button with Shape Template: click event not fired when background is set

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have problem with following **shape-based control-template**:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EllipseButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Navy" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The problem is, that button **does not generate click event**, when button's **background property is set** (see `Background="White"`). If background is not set click event is fired.

```
<Button x:Name="Button" 
                Content="Click" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Template="{StaticResource EllipseButton}"
                Background="White" <-- PROBLEMATIC PROPERTY
                />
```

How can I safely bind Button.Background property to Elipse.Fill property without loosing click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where was the problem. I was **wrongly setting background in trigger section**. Instead of setting background to button, I should set Fill property of the Ellipse:

```
    ...
    <Ellipse Name="Ellipse" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    ...
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Ellipse" Property="Fill" Value="Navy" />
    </Trigger>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your button wrong. If you set the background to white and if the template binding of the Ellipse's binding is not defined elsewhere, then WPF will not do hit test on your custom button. Please check the TemplateBinding bind, it's not correct.